# Vue.js firebase instance - Users UID as database ref

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuefire

Is it possible to get the following example working? I have pushed some objects into the firebase realtime-database and the reference is the UID of the signed in user. But even if I want to query  the object at the reference which we can get from firebase.auth.currentUser.uid, I'm getting an error uid of NULL. Is there a way to get this functionality working?

The Vue.js Code:

```
import firebase from '.././firebase';
import { db } from '.././firebase';



export default {
    name: 'addMatch',
    data() {
        return{
            tableTennisData: [],
            player1Name: '',
            player2Name: '', 
            //Game 1
            firstMatchPlayer1Game1: '',
            firstMatchPlayer1Game2: '',
            firstMatchPlayer1Game3: '',
            firstMatchPlayer1Game4: '',
            firstMatchPlayer1Game5: '',
      }
    },

    firebase: {
        tableTennisData: db.ref(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('tableTennis'), // UID Of Null error!
    },
        addMatch: function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const obj = {
            //Game 1
            player1Name: this.player1Name,
            player2Name: this.player2Name,
            firstMatchPlayer1Game1: this.firstMatchPlayer1Game1,
            firstMatchPlayer1Game2: this.firstMatchPlayer1Game2,
            firstMatchPlayer1Game3: this.firstMatchPlayer1Game3,
            firstMatchPlayer1Game4: this.firstMatchPlayer1Game4,
            firstMatchPlayer1Game5: this.firstMatchPlayer1Game5,
            }
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (){
                db.ref(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('tableTennis').push(obj);
            });

            console.log(obj);
        },

    },
```

Comment: "I'm getting an error uid of NULL" What is the exact error message you get, and on what line does this happen?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank for your answer :) I'm getting the error by assigning the firebase database objects to the "tableTennisData" Array. There is a comment at the specific line. The error-message: "addMatch.vue?c217:231 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How can I wrap the Firebase object from Vue into the onAuthStateChange handler? It is difficult because of The Vue.js Syntax...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the user isn't signed in yet.

Keep in mind that it takes a moment for Firebase to restore the user's authentication state when you load a page. If you call `auth.currentUser` before that, you will get back `null`.

```
tableTennisData: db.ref(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('tableTennis'),
```

I don't see where you call this code, but you'll want to wrap it in an `onAuthStateChanged` handler as you already do in `addMatch`.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. But how am I able to wrap it into the  onAuthStateChange handler?